# MySQL requires restart in Terminal every time laptop is restarted. 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: command-line, mysql, reboot, restart, documentation

I installed MySQL a few weeks ago. The problem now is that every time my laptop is restarted I also have to manually restart MySQL in terminal via:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

The errors I get before executing that command line (follows:)

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

$ /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command ad your mysql start automatically:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```